# Where is data saved if I do not have an hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, livecd, liveusb

I know I can boot a computer using a "live CD" or a "live USB", but where does the system store data, if there's no external memory support (e.g. a hard-disk)? Is the data directly stored in the RAM? If that's the case, when the RAM is full, would the computer crash?

Comment: Actually its not true. A system will POST without a harddrive attached. It has to has at least a videocard and memory installed to boot, and will then try to find anything it can boot to and displays an error if it can't find any. A USB drive, a CDRom Drive or even boot from LAN are options allowed to boot.

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard I'm interested to know what computers you have encountered that refuse to boot without a hard disk drive. I haven't met one. Corporations frequently run off-the-shelf consumer grade desktop systems as diskless workstations. Most computers also do not really distinguish between a fixed hard drive and, say, a removable USB disk,  for boot purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data is only stored to locations that can contain it, such as a Harddrive or to a chip that can store memory while powered off, such as a Memory card (SD, MMC, xD, etc)

During a live CD session, data will be stored to any device that can contain it if it detects such, including an iPod if attached (yes I had this happened to me once). It will use the memory (RAM) for temporary storage.

If at shutdown no other writable memory is found, the session simply won't be stored, because a CD is a ROM (Read Only Memory) and its data cannot be changed, unless working with a writable cd in a CD writer.

EDIT2:
Jog points out that: virtual HDDs can also be used which can exist in volatile memory, as it gets filled you get bog-standard low diskspace warnings. The OS doesn't care if the medium will lose data when powered off as long as it thinks it is writing to a disk. This is how diskless PCs that boot from a virtual disk server work.

EDIT: What will happen if the RAM is full?
An operating system has 2 types of memory. the upper memory and lower memory. Today, the low memory is not something that you'll see, but the technique is still used. Basically a small portion of memory is reserved for OS specific functions, such as reading and writing to the higher memory part. If th high memory part becomes full, the low memory part will then start to free memory if capable, or display a message that there isn't enough memory to complete the task.

Because of the 2 memory segments, a system won't crash if it runs out of memory unless a programming error allows the lower memory section to get out of space too.

Comment: "Data is only stored to locations that can contain it, such as a Harddrive or to a chip that can store memory while powered off, such as a Memory card (SD, MMC, xD, etc)":-    You might want to change that to include virtual HDDs which can exist in volatile memory, as it gets filled you get bog-standard low diskspace warnings. The OS doesn't care if the medium will lose data when powered off as long as it thinks it is writing to a disk. This is how diskless PCs that boot from a virtual disk server work.

Answer (score 0):

The **OS doesn't need to store any data permanently** in writable memory regions except when the user changes some persistent settings. But persistent settings are typically disallowed on Live CDs so basically you have nothing to write to disk. All of the necessary data for system startup are already available on the boot medium, in this case some type of read-only memory. Live sessions will use [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) to store temporary data on RAM and [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS) to overlay some system folders

> A read-only file system, such as on a CD-ROM has the drawback of being unable to save any current working data. For this reason, a read-only file system is often merged with a temporary writable file system in the form of a RAM disk. Often the default Linux directories "/home" (containing users' personal files and configuration files) and "/var" (containing variable data) are kept in ramdisk, because the system updates them frequently. Puppy Linux and some other live CDs allow a configuration and added files to be written and used in later sessions.
>
> In modern live CDs, a read-only file system is merged with a RAM drive using transparent techniques such as UnionFS, AuFS or EWF. Boot loaders like syslinux can boot ISO files from USB memory devices.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD#Creation

Many tiny Linux distros like [Slax](http://www.slax.org/), [SliTax](http://slitaz.org/en/) or [PuppyLinux](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/HowPuppyWorks?redirect=no) even load the whole root file system onto a RAM disk to make a smoother experience. See [List of Linux distributions that run from RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM)

Obviously all of that that need more memory, therefore live CDs are only actually commonly used after RAM became bigger and cheaper

> The term "live CD" was coined because, after typical PC RAM was large enough and 52x speed CD drives and CD burners were widespread among PC owners, it finally became convenient and practical to boot the kernel and run X11, a window manager and GUI applications directly from a CD without disturbing the OS on the hard disk.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD#Linux

Previously one disadvantage of running live CDs without any writable medium is that you have no space for the swap file, which may cause problems if you need too much memory. In recent years this won't be a problem anymore because a feature called [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) has been merged into the mainline kernel and the swap partition can be stored compressed on RAM. Many Linux distros like [Lubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20150819151859/http://linuxvillage.org/en/2013/10/next-lubuntu-provided-with-zram-enabled/) or [Fedora](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-33-Aims-SWAP-On-ZRAM) even enable zram by default because it's so fast compared to swap on disk. So does [ChromeOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20130331021835/https://www.chromestory.com/2013/03/google-enabling-zram-for-chrome-os-by-default/). [Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/319933/what-is-memory-compression-in-windows-10/) and [macOS](https://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/12/compressed-memory-in-os-x-109-mavericks-aims-to-free-ram-extend-battery-life) also have similar [pagefile compression techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory_compression) which are enabled by default

But **what happens when memory becomes low even after zram is being used?** Then the [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) ([Out Of Memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html)) manager in the Linux kernel will run and kill the process(es) with a high [`oom_badness()` score](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60952830/995714)

Later Linux versions also introduced a feature called [casper -rw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2566121/995714) in order to store system settings and/or some user files for a live CD/USB in a physical or loop partition. This is mainly used on [live USBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB)

Comment: I haven't seen any linux's (live or other) that didn't use some form of temporary filesystem, an overlay/overlayfs, or aufs (forms of ramfs/tmpfs apparently), are there some that really boot & work completely without any form of saving temporary files? Even router software like dd-wrt/openwrt keeps temporary files in ram. And zram won't completely solve all out-of-ram problems, programs will always want more-more-more, but it's supposed to help. And I think any Ubuntu-based os can also load everything in ram with the `toram` boot option (many Debian based os's too)

Comment: @Xen2050 of course there are procfs, sysfs... that all Linux systems have. I'm talking about /tmp and /var which is often on a non-volatile medium on most distros but not on a live CD. The OP is asking about live CDs so it's irrelevant what others do. They can store data on RAM if they want, but it's not a necessity like a live distro